# view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, dict, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a list

Tags: python, pytube

TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, dict, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a list.

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from pytube import YouTube
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/youtube', methods=['POST'])
def hello_world():
    url = request.form['d_url']
    yt_video = YouTube(url)
    videos = yt_video.streams
    res_list = list(enumerate(videos))
    return res_list

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug =True)
```

Comment: What's wrong? The error is pretty straight forward, you can't return a list.

Comment: I want to return list.

Comment: Want to return all results in json format that received in res_list

Comment: Well, you can't, so your best bet will probably be to return it as a string/dictionary/tuple then reconvert it outside

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you cannot return a list directly from flask.view you have to convert it to json object.

Apparently directly using `jsonify` from Flask did not as it could not serialize the Stream object in res_list. When doing `jsonify(res_list)` I got the following error:

```
TypeError: Object of type Stream is not JSON serializable
```

Using [jsonpickle](https://pypi.org/project/jsonpickle/) did the job. Below code is working:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from pytube import YouTube
import jsonpickle

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/youtube', methods=['POST'])
def hello_world():
    url = request.form['d_url'] #'http://youtube.com/watch?v=9bZkp7q19f0'
    yt_video = YouTube(url)
    videos = yt_video.streams
    res_list = list(enumerate(videos))
    return jsonpickle.encode(res_list)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug =True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try json.dumps function

```
import json
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from pytube import YouTube
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/youtube', methods=['POST'])
def hello_world():
url = request.form['d_url']
yt_video = YouTube(url)
videos = yt_video.streams
res_list = list(enumerate(videos))
json.dumps(res_list)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug =True)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).